# include exist in begin transaction

Tags: sql-server

if a membered does not exist in Notes table, then the insert line before should be rolledback. I thought by putting both lines in the Begin transaction, it would rollback, but because no error is thrown, it executes the insert command. How do I throw an error if membered does not exist, so that the whole block of code is rolled back?

```
begin try
    begin transaction
        insert into notes (memberid, NoteEffDate, LoginName, NoteDesc) values (367737, GETDATE(), 'marc', 'blah blah')
        IF EXISTS (SELECT memberid FROM notes WHERE memberid =4774769)
        begin
        update notes set notedesc = 'hello there' where memberid = 4774769
        end
    commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        select ERROR_MESSAGE()

        end catch
        go
```

Comment: It is not really a good idea to use an error for control flow. Why can't you do the check for existence first?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use some version of [Sam Saffron's upsert method](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx).

A rough version of what a procedure would look like for that:

```
create procedure dbo.notes_upsert (
    @memberid int
  , @notesdesc varchar(256)
  , @loginname varchar(256)
  ) as 
begin
  set nocount on;
  set xact_abort on;
  begin tran
    update notes (with serializable)
      set   notedesc = @notedesc
      where memberid = @memberid;
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin;
      insert into notes (memberid, NoteEffDate, LoginName, NoteDesc) 
      values (@memberid, getdate(), @loginname, @notesdesc);
    end;
  commit tran
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* RaiseError in your Try Block.

```
begin try
begin transaction
    insert into notes (memberid, NoteEffDate, LoginName, NoteDesc) values (367737, GETDATE(), 'marc', 'blah blah')
    IF EXISTS (SELECT memberid FROM notes WHERE memberid =4774769)
    begin
    update notes set notedesc = 'hello there' where memberid = 4774769
    end
    ELSE 

-- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to   
-- jump to the CATCH block.  
RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.  
           16, -- Severity.  
           1 -- State.  
           ); 
commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()

    end catch
    go
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apologies for late reply, but this was my first post on stack overflow and i was expecting an email notification if I received a response. I will check out the answers and revert. Thanks